# How do you stop focus going to the tab when clicking in the tabs content?

Tags: javafx-8

The program below shows a button and a label in a tab. The button has focus on start up. If you click anywhere in the content area apart from on the button, the button loses focus and the tab gains focus.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FocusTest  extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        tabPane.setFocusTraversable(false);
        Scene scene = new Scene(tabPane, 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        Tab tab = new Tab("Tab 1");
        FlowPane contentPane = new FlowPane();
        /*contentPane.setOnMousePressed(MouseEvent::consume);*/
        tab.setContent(contentPane);
        tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab, new Tab("Tab 2"));
        Button button = new Button("Button");
        Label label = new Label("Label");
        contentPane.getChildren().addAll(button, label);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

I don't think the button should lose focus when clicking in the tab's content area. I still want to be able to focus the tab by clicking on the tab's name/text bit and use the shortcut keys to change tab.

I couldn't find a way to do it using the Tab or the TabPane but if I add a mouse pressed listener on the content pane (see commented out code above) I do get the behaviour I require but it feels like a bit of a hack. And I would have to set a listener on every item in tab pane.

So I suppose my question is, is there a better way to do this?

---

I raised an issue for this:

https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-37941

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can request focus to the Button when the contentPane (FlowPane) is clicked here is the modified version of your code:

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.*;
    import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
    import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class FocusTest  extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
    tabPane.setFocusTraversable(false);
    Scene scene = new Scene(tabPane, 500, 500);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    final Button button = new Button("Button");// I moved this here and added final
    Tab tab = new Tab("Tab 1");
    FlowPane contentPane = new FlowPane();
    contentPane.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {//I think this is what you are looking for
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            button.requestFocus();
        }
    });                          
    tab.setContent(contentPane);
    tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab, new Tab("Tab 2"));

    Label label = new Label("Label");
    contentPane.getChildren().addAll(button, label);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}
}
```

If you have any question or would like to know how to do the same thing with multiple buttons or other object comment
  I hope this will help you!

Comment: thanks for trying to be helpful :-) Just, this doesn't solve the problem (button shouldn't loose focus at all). Registering a mouseListener as done in the OPs code works fine to that effect, no need to explicitly requestFocus back if it never lost it ...